# What JWT claims from Azure AD tokens can be safely used for user mappings?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We use OAuth 2.0 to obtain JWT tokens from an Azure AD. In our application, we have used the value of the 'upn' claim to identify an associated internal username.

The [Azure AD Token Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-token-and-claims) documents the **upn** claim as a "User Principal Name", which as far as I understand is a username following the addr-spec format (i.e. user@domain). This works well for users created within the Azure AD Tenant. To my surprise, however, the **upn** claim seems to be gone if the authenticated user is sync'ed from a different AD. This behavior does not seem to be documented anywhere.

1. Where can I find documentation on when the **upn** is guaranteed to be in a token?
2. What are reliable alternative claims that I can use instead? Preferably claims guaranteed to be of the form "user/domain", as that matches our model best. I have considered the following:

   - **unique_name**: I have only observed this to be equal to **upn**, but I am not sure where it comes from. Confusingly, the [token reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-token-and-claims) says: *This value is **not** guaranteed to be unique within a tenant and is designed to be used only for display purposes.* (emphasis mine)
   - **email**: This too seems to be equal to **upn**, but again, where is it sourced from? In the management portal, I have tried putting a different value in every email related field associated with the user, but none of them seem to be propagated to this claim. It therefore appears that this field is *not actually an email*.

I want to be absolutely sure that our application will be able to handle all tokens issued by Azure AD, so I am hesitant to use any of the above claims unless I have some documentation that explains their actual semantics.

Comment: I think this is related to your question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oidce/55c0a84d-48e7-4043-91f8-9ebd0a51ab68; is I interpret it, unique_name is mandatory in the response whereas upn is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Where can I find documentation on when the upn is guaranteed to be in a token?

There is no such document about how this claim is guaranteed. Based on the test, it is as you mentioned that only be issued when the users is not a external user.

> What are reliable alternative claims that I can use instead? Preferably claims guaranteed to be of the form "user/domain", as that matches our model best. I have considered the following:

We can use the `oid` claim to map the users. This claim is *contains a unique identifier of an object in Azure AD. This value is immutable and cannot be reassigned or reused. Use the object ID to identify an object in queries to Azure AD.*

And if you have any feedback about the Azure document, you can try to submit the feedback from **Is this page is helpful?** at the right bottom page to help improving the document.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I take it that there is no documentation on the semantics of **unique_name** and **email**, then? The lack of uniqueness is not necessarily a problem (multiple AD principals could still identify the same user within our application).

Answer (score 0):

While it is fairly common for a User’s UPN and primary email address to be the same thing, that isn’t guaranteed (nor is the existence of UPN as you’ve noticed). So you should operate under the assumption that UPN != email address. If you need to know the email address, you should make a Graph call and search using the oid.