# unique_name claim - which user attribute?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

The *id_token* contains a claim whose name is `unique_name`. Its value appears to be the same as that of the `upn` claim. Which User entity attribute provides the value for this claim?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What JWT claims from Azure AD tokens can be safely used for user mappings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972416/what-jwt-claims-from-azure-ad-tokens-can-be-safely-used-for-user-mappings)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on my observations, the `upn` claim does not show up for guest users.
The `unique_name` however does show up for all users.

It is not always something that can be displayed, for example for a Guest I added it looks like this:

```
live.com#first.last@gmail.com
```

So in this case it is actually a personal MS account, as indicated by the live.com# prefix.

In the case of a guest from another AAD, the value is their UPN with no prefix.

Though that said if you need a unique identifier for the user that does not change,
you can use either the `oid` or `sub` claims.
The former is the object id for the user which can be used in calls to MS Graph API for example, while the latter is a unique identifier for the user in context to your app.
So the object id will be the same across all apps, and the subject will be unique within one app.

Comment: Addendum: `unique_name` and `upn` are both part of the OpenID Connect 1.0 Protocol Extensions, and indeed `unique_name` is a _required_ claim, while `upn` is not:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oidce/55c0a84d-48e7-4043-91f8-9ebd0a51ab68

Comment: Before learning about this, we experimented with the standard `email` claim, but we encountered AAD tenants where the `email` claim existed _only_ for guests, not for regular users.

Comment: The unique_name claim is a v1 endpoint claim, make sure that your application is configured to use the /oauth2/v2.0/authorize endpoint rather than the v1 /oauth/authorize endpoint if you want to get upn claim instead of the unique_name claim for guest users containing live.com#first.last format

Answer (score 1):

The unique_name claim is a unique identifier for that can be displayed to the user, this is usually a user principal name (UPN) in [id-token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code).  And many of the tokens issued by Azure AD are implemented as JSON Web Tokens, or JWTs. 
For the details, please read [Azure AD token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-id-and-access-tokens).